# How to invoker REST Apis from thingsboard dashboard widget's Code

Tags: thingsboard

What dependencies do I need to add to be able to conveniently make REST Api calls from things board widget's angular JS code ?

Answer (score 0):

From a browsers javascript perspective you don't need any extras to use a REST-Api.
You can perform http requests and you can parse and stringify JSON-data.

This is also true for widgets in Thingsboard, since they are executed by the browser on the client-side.